My mobile robot doesn't move in any direction
I've created a mobile robot and applied the differential drive controllers to its wheels. However, while the wheels actually moves (the rotation is on) the robot stays still. How can I fix such problem?

?xml version="1.0"?>


    <link name="world">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </link>

    <joint name="dummy" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world"/>
        <child link="amr_body"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="left_wheel">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 -0.37 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/visual/left_wheel.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 -0.37 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/collision/left_wheel.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 -0.37 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <link name="right_wheel">
        <inertial>     
            <origin xyz="0 0.37 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/visual/right_wheel.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0.37 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/collision/right_wheel.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0.37 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <link name="amr_body">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/visual/amr_body.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/collision/amr_body.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <link name="amr_rialzo">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0.1" ixz="0.1" iyy="0.1" iyz="0.1" izz="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/visual/amr_rialzo.dae" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://amr/collision/amr_rialzo.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="amr_body"/>
        <child link="left_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0.37 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <limit velocity="0.35" effort="100"/>
        <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="amr_body"/>
        <child link="right_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0 -0.37 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <limit velocity="0.35" effort="100"/>
        <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="rialzo_joint" type="prismatic">
        <parent link="amr_body"/>
        <child link="amr_rialzo"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="0" upper="0.06" velocity="0.02" effort="100"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>

    <transmission name="trans_rialzo_joint" >
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name = "rialzo_joint" >
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor_rialzo_joint" >
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>50</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

    <transmission name="trans_left_wheel_joint" >
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name = "left_wheel_joint" >
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor_left_wheel_joint" >
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

    <transmission name="trans_right_wheel_joint" >
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name = "right_wheel_joint" >
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="motor_right_wheel_joint" >
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>10</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
            <robotNamespace>/amr</robotNamespace>
              <robotParam>robot_description</robotParam>
              <controlPeriod>0.001</controlPeriod>
              <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
              <legacyModeNS>true</legacyModeNS>
        </plugin>
        <plugin name='diff_drive' filename='libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so'>
            <!-- Wheel Information -->
            <leftJoint>left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
            <wheelSeparation>0.73</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.2</wheelDiameter>
            <!-- Limits -->
            <wheelTorque>1000</wheelTorque>
            <wheelAcceleration>0.6</wheelAcceleration>
            <!-- Output -->
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <robotBaseFrame>world</robotBaseFrame>
            <publishOdomTF>true</publishOdomTF>
            <publishWheelTF>true</publishWheelTF>
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100</updateRate>
            <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
            <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
            <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
            <rosDebugLevel>na</rosDebugLevel>
            <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
            <publishTf>1</publishTf>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

This is the urdf of the robot.
EDIT 1:
As you can see in the image, after NOT modifying the visual and collision origin, the wheel is completely detached from the robot.

EDIT 2: New inertia parameters
For the wheels:
<inertia ixx="0.015" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.015" iyz="0" izz="0.025"/>

For the AMR_body:
<inertia ixx="9.5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="19.02" iyz="0" izz="27.08"/>

For the AMR_rialzo :
<inertia ixx="11" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="17.17" iyz="0" izz="20.5"/>


If I had to say please check the following tips:

Why do you need the frame world in your urdf? Is it the one you are using as base_footprint? You should stick to the REP convention when definying frames. I suppose amr_body is your base_link.

Double check that the wheels do turn correctly using the joint_state_publisher_gui. You have defined the axis tag of the wheel's joints differently, so perhaps you are rotating each wheel contrary and cancelling the movement. I would place the robot on air and move the wheels and check they move as they suppose to.

Check the collision boxes. I can't share a picture but you have a tab in Gazebo where you can see collision boxes. Make sure the model is not collisioning with the floor forcing it to stick to it.

In the diff_drive plugin, the frame base param is expecting the base frame of the robot. Normally, this is base_link, which I understand should be your amr_body.

Last, why are you changing the origin of the inertial tag of the wheels? You are already setting the position in the joint tag. Changing the origin tag of inertial is used when you need to change the CoM (Center of Mass) of the link, which for a wheel (0,0,0) should be enough (depending where you defined the origin of the link and the model you could use XACRO to include the offset to the center of the wheel).


Hope any of these ones solve your problem.
Edit 1: Normally, when you define the link itself, you don't change any origin tags, since you don't want to apply any offset from the "origin of your link", in exception inertial. If you have a box (for example) the origin normally is in it's base, so you would add height/2 z offset in inertial tag so just the CoM is modified. But collision and visual origin tags should be set to 0 0 0 so when you pick the box in Gazebo, or move it via cmd, you move it knowing that the link of the frame is in its base.
Then you use the joint tag to add the wheel to your robot_base and there is where you need to set the origin tag to put your child frame in the correct position.
You can try comparing the link frame (Gazebo) and the joint frame (RVIZ) and see if they are displayed correctly. Could you please add a picture of both of them?
Also, here I attach you a fragment as example of URDF:
<link name="structure">
    <inertial>
        <mass value="8.5" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
        <inertia ixx="0.258206919587897" ixy="-3.02556764651227E-06" ixz="6.93128254044665E-06" iyy="0.296960404834235" iyz="-0.0001246582297324" izz="0.153127456260744" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="file://$(find husky_ual_description)/meshes/Structure.dae" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="White">
            <color rgba="0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="file://$(find husky_ual_description)/meshes/Structure.dae" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>
<joint name="structure_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="structure" />
    <origin xyz="0.05 0.0 0.06" rpy="0.0 0 1.5708" />
</joint>

Don't pay attention to the values of inertia, but as you can see, the relative pose between base_link and structure is impossed by the joint, and not the link itself. If I modify the code in the link properties, I would establish offsets to the joint it is added.
Edit 2: So, I encourage you hardly to follow the tutorials published by ROS and Gazebo, since there is a lot to do here.

First, your launch isn't written correctly, one of your param files isn't named as you wrote in the launch (the one of the joint_states). How are you launching a launch file which crashes with this typo?

Changing this allowed me to crash my Gazebo. I suppose your machine is a really good one, but this is caused because of your URDF file. You shouldn't include stls or daes in your collision tags, because this is a really difficult stuff to compute, and it is preferable to use tags such as box and cylinder.

Also, you are using the libgazebo_ros_diff_drive plugin from Gazebo to simulate a differential drive, so why are you using ROS Control as well? I would like to advice to use gazebo plugins first, and if needed step into ros_control, since the difficult is bigger imo.


Please, read again all my questions and try to answer every each one. If not, I won't be able to keep helping you. Attach pictures of collisions and joints from Gazebo (if you are able to run it).

Changed from world to amr_body, wheels spin in the same direction. Still doesn't work.

For what concerns the origin of inertial, I moved since I've assumed that the CoMs are detected from the mesh files. Am I wrong?

Please check the edited answer

Check the edited question please.

I haven't seen no comments from the other points I have mentioned. Try to test each one independently and see if it improves. I think you must be doing something wrong that we cannot see and that's the reason why the TFs are not publishing properly. You can see that the link of the wheel seems to be inside the robot, while the visual tag (and probably the collision one as well) are with an offset not desired. You had already seen another example with a Kuka arm and if you check the urdf, they modify the translation and rotation of links using the joint, not in the definition of the link.

The wheels' links are indeed inside the robot, since the centre of rotation of the wheel is at those coordinates (0 -0.37 -0.1). If I set all origin tag at (0,0,0) then the wheel will rotate around a wrong point.

Moreover, by setting the link origin tag at (0,0,0) and modifying only the joint origin, I get the same situation as in the image I've attached.

Could you provide the files needed to launch the URDF? I tried my best to help you without launching the model, so I guess is the next step. You can share a Google Drive link or something similar.

I've uploaded all the file in a MEGA folder. Thanks for your time and help. Here:  https://mega.nz/folder/7B5FXZzJ#T0jmpQVML2lWnC_2x6Ag6A

I removed the world link and now it moves. Only problem is that while it moves, it does bounce a lot. But really a lot.

The folder doesn't contain the dae's and stl's needed to reproduce your robot. For the bouncing effect it could be due to the variables you used for inertia calculation. For instance you used the same inertia for the wheels and the body, and the weight of the body is 250 kgs, which is quite big for the purpose. Try using xacro constants to calculate the intertias automatically like in this example

Unofortunately, I don't have enough accurate data concerning the masses or the material of the robot. Thus, the inertia parameters are approximated. Check the new inertia parameters. Also, the folder now contains .stl and .dae files.

Zoom in to see if the wheels are touching the floor, and that the collision bottom is not.  (Try raising the z value of your collision pose - you have z as 0, but it needs to be more than half the z height of the amr_body)
I just had the exact same issue with my custom bot sdf and indeed my wheels were not touching the floor because the z of my body collision was 0.
See Gazebo Classic: odom plugin not moving "floating in air" bot
